# Creating a PKCS12 File using Openssl.net

Tags: .net, ssl, openssl, xamarin

I am trying to use OpenSSL.NET to generate a P12 file from a cert and key (also generated using openssl.net).
My function is as follows:

```
GenerateP12(string pwd, RSA key, string pemcert)
{
    BIO certbio = new BIO(pemcert);
    X509Certificate x = new X509Certificate(certbio);
    CryptoKey crytokey = new CryptoKey(key);
    PKCS12 p12 = new PKCS12(pwd, cryptokey, x, ca);
    BIO a = BIO.MemoryBuffer();
    p12.write(a);
    // Write 'a' to some file.
}
```

However, when I try to imort that key into a .NET X509Certificate2 object, I get a "Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate".

If I get the private key in pem format, using:

```
key.PrivateKeyAsPEM
```

and write that to a file, along with the cert pem, and then run the following openssl command from the terminal:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -aes256 -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out outfile.crt
```

Importing into the X509Certificate2 object works fine.

Does anyone know how I can generate a PKCS12 using OpenSSL.NET, that would give me a similar file as to the one that gets generated when using the openssl commandline tool?

Thanks,

**Update:**
It looks like the P12 I am generating in code is formatted incorrectly; if I export it to a file, and then try to get info on it using the openssl commandline:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in myp12.p12
```

I get the following errors:

```
140735263351648:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:142:
140735263351648:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1306:
140735263351648:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:831:
140735263351648:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=version, Type=PKCS12
```

Which explains why attempting to import it into a .NET X509Certificate2 object fails.
I also changed the Openssl.NET API I was using, so that my code now looks as follows:

```
string GenerateP12(string pwd, CryptoKey key, string cert)
{
    BIO certbio = new BIO(cert);
    BIO a = BIO.MemoryBuffer();
    X509Certificate x = new X509Certificate(certbio);
    Stack<X509Certificate>ca = new Stack<X509Certificate>();
    PKCS12 p12 = new PKCS12(pwd, "test", key, x, ca, SHA1_3DES, SHA1_RC2_40, 0, KEY_DEFAULT);
    p12.Write(a);
    return a.ReadString();
}
```

(I am using the expanded function, since I need to specify the algorithms to use, and the defaults are not the same as what I need).

Comment: Did you try other libraries, like SecureBlackbox? They should be able to do things you described.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky I hadn't. The main reason I was using openssl was that I am using it in other locations, and because its FIPS approved.

Comment: You may use this link on how to convert a cert and key to PKCS#12 file. https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I actually came across that site before, and its definitely really helpful from the perspective of what commandline options to use, but I am trying to do it programatically using .NET

Comment: Okay. And what if you don't include CA in PKCS12? Also, can you upload that PKCS#12 data with password somewhere, so I can check it on my side?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky, I added more info in the summary (the PKCS12 object I generated through code appears to not be formatted correctly). However, I am still trying to figure out if the PKCS12 object I am creating is not being set right, or my exporting of it is not correct (based on my updated code in the summary).

Answer (score 2):

Since this post came across when I was looking for a solution to the same issue, I want to share a way how to get this done without saving to the file system first.

The simplest way I got this done:

```
 ...
 using (var p12 = new PKCS12(...))
 using (var bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer())
 {
      p12.Write(bio);
      return bio.ReadBytes((int) bio.BytesPending).Array; // returns byte[]
 }
 ...

 // return value can be saved like this
 File.WriteAllBytes("filename", result);
```

Another way of getting the bytes from a p12 would be to use `MemoryStream`:

```
 ...
 using (var p12 = new PKCS12(...))
 using (var bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer())
 {
     p12.Write(bio);
     const int bufferSize = 4096;
     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         while (bio.BytesPending > 0)
         {
             var segment = bio.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
             memoryStream.Write(segment.Array, 0, segment.Count);
         }
         return memoryStream.ToArray(); // returns byte[]
     }
 }
 ...

 // return value can be saved like this
 File.WriteAllBytes("filename", result);
```

I probably would prefer the first solution because its shorter and doesn't create so many intermediary arrays. I wonder how big such certificates might actually get. My scenarios were always way below 4 KB. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing, if anyone comes across a similar issue, is that instead of using the BIO object to export the contents to a string, I ended up writing it directly to a file:

```
BIO certbio = new BIO(cert);
BIO a = BIO.File(myfile, "wb");
X509Certificate x = new X509Certificate(certbio);
Stack<X509Certificate>ca = new Stack<X509Certificate>();
PKCS12 p12 = new PKCS12(pwd, "test", key, x, ca, SHA1_3DES, SHA1_RC2_40, 0, KEY_DEFAULT);
p12.Write(a);
byte []data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(myfile);
return data;
```

And this flow works as expected. It does have the additional step of having to write the data to a file first, but at least that points to the way i was doing the export initially as being the culprit.